# Multiplas @ElementCollection em duas diferentes classes @Embeddable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Eu tenho uma entidade com duas classes **Embedded** do mesmo tipo e cada uma tem uma **ElementCollection** do mesmo tipo, também. A lógica de negócio parece estar correta, mas eu estou experimentando alguns problemas com a falta de conhecimento na JPA.

Aqui vão minhas classes:

```
@Entity
public class Etapa extends EntidadeBase {

    @Embedded
    private CronogramaDeDesembolso cronogramaDeReceita;

    @Embedded
    private CronogramaDeDesembolso cronogramaDeDespesa;
}

@Embeddable
public class CronogramaDeDesembolso {

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Parcela> parcelas;
}
```

Eu estou recebendo o seguinte log de erro:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: nexxus.convenioestadual.dominio.planodetrabalho.etapa.Etapa.cronogramaDeReceita.parcelas

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar errado e como arrumar?

Comment: Você provavelmente está atribuindo o mesmo objeto a `cronogramaDeReceita` e `cronogramaDeDespesa` OU `parcelas` é a mesma coleção nesses cronogramas, mesmo eles sendo instâncias distintas. Inclua como está criando estes objetos que fica mais fácil de ajudar

Comment: Era exatamente este o problema. Estávamos atribuindo o mesmo objeto para receita e despesa. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O hibernate irá apresentar este problema quando tentar persistir mais de uma entidade por ele gerenciada que compartilham a mesma instância de uma coleção.

Por exemplo, este cenário irá apresentar este problema:

```
final Parcela parcela01 = ...
final Parcela parcela02 = ...

final List<Parcela> parcelas = Stream.of(parcela01, parcela02).collect(Collectors.toList());

final CronogramaDeDesembolso despesa = ...
despesa.setParcelas(parcelas);

final CronogramaDeDesembolso receita = ...
receita.setParcelas(parcelas);

final Etapa etapa = ...
etapa.setCronogramaDeDespesa(despesa);
etapa.setCronogramaDeReceita(receita);

// fazer o que mais for necessário e atualizar a instância (persist/merge/etc.)
em.persist(etapa);
```

É importante observar que o que não se deve ser a mesma é a coleção, os itens da coleção podem ser os mesmo. A solução neste caso é apenas ter uma outra coleção, algo assim:

```
final Parcela parcela01 = ...
final Parcela parcela02 = ...

final List<Parcela> parcelasDespesa = Stream.of(parcela01, parcela02).collect(Collectors.toList());
final List<Parcela> parcelasReceita = Stream.of(parcela01, parcela02).collect(Collectors.toList());

final CronogramaDeDesembolso despesa = ...
despesa.setParcelas(parcelasDespesa);

final CronogramaDeDesembolso receita = ...
receita.setParcelas(parcelasReceita);

final Etapa etapa = ...
etapa.setCronogramaDeDespesa(despesa);
etapa.setCronogramaDeReceita(receita);
```

Perceba que são gerados objetos diferentes, ao coletarmos do *stream*. Apenas ter duas coleções diferente, mas que recebe da anterior, também acarretará no problema, algo como isto:

```
final List<Parcela> parcelasDespesa = Stream.of(parcela01, parcela02).collect(Collectors.toList());
final List<Parcela> parcelasReceita = parcelasDespesa;
```

Existem outros cenários que isto também ocorre, mesmo que menos comuns, como em aplicações que processam concorrendo pela mesma coleção. Em todos os cenários, no entanto, a causa é a mesma, a mesma instância da coleção presente em diferente instâncias gerenciadas pelo *provider*.

O ponto central é: não compatilhe coleções entre diferentes objetos que estão ou serão gerenciados pelo hibernate :)

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado, @BrunoCésar